# What is configuration binding in felix

Tags: java, aem, apache-felix

I've seen that after creating a new Felix Configuration in my java class and 
while configuring that in Felix console, under 'Configuration Binding' it says 'Unbound or New Configuration' with no value for bundle field along with the configuration.

After changing the configuration, 'Configuration Binding' shows symbolic name of the bundle.
I'm confused, What is the concept of Configuration binding.
I've created a configuration in my bundle, then why in felix console i have to save the configuration first to see the value of 'Configuration Binding'

Comment: how do you create a configuration in your bundle ?

Comment: @Jérémie I create a configuration with @Component(metatype=true) annotation